# CentOS7 Targetcli Configuration lost after server reboot

Tags: centos7, lvm, iscsi, open-iscsi

Targetcli configuration got lost after server was rebooted, i tried to restore configuration from backup files with `targetcli restoreconfig <backupFile>` configuration is not restored output message of the command `storageobjects or targets present, not restoring`. below are outputs of `targetcli ls` and `systemctl status -l target`

```
targetcli ls
o- / ................................................................................................ [...]
  o- backstores ..................................................................................... [...]
  | o- block ......................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- fileio ........................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi ......................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk ....................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi ................................................................................... [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2017-01.com.urgroup-tz:target ........................................................ [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 ...................................................................... [no-gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls ................................................................................. [ACLs: 1]
  |     | o- iqn.2017-01.com.urgroup-tz:initiator ........................................ [Mapped LUNs: 0]
  |     o- luns ................................................................................. [LUNs: 0]
  |     o- portals ........................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ............................................................................ [OK]
  o- loopback ................................................................................ [Targets: 0]

# systemctl status -l target
● target.service - Restore LIO kernel target configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/target.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Ij 2017-03-10 17:18:43 EST; 1 day 18h ago
 Main PID: 1342 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/target.service

Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not create StorageObject tools_disk: Cannot configure StorageObject because device /dev/cl/tools_lv is already in use, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not create StorageObject bamboo_disk: Cannot configure StorageObject because device /dev/cl/bamboo_lv is already in use, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not create StorageObject metadata_disk: Cannot configure StorageObject because device /dev/cl/ovirt_domain_metadata is already in use, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching StorageObject for LUN 2, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching StorageObject for LUN 1, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching StorageObject for LUN 0, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching TPG LUN 0 for MappedLUN 0, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching TPG LUN 1 for MappedLUN 1, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 target[1342]: Could not find matching TPG LUN 2 for MappedLUN 2, skipped
Mac 10 17:18:43 server1 systemd[1]: Started Restore LIO kernel target configuration.
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the service is enabled before you reboot:

systemctl enable target

Helps here.

mistige

Answer (score 1):

In case you use LVM managed storage pool for backstore devices, you should make certain that LVM/Devicemapper discards the second layer VGs/LVs.

What i meant by second layer VGs/LVs; for example:

Assume that the below LVs (DISK_1) has another VG initilized by iSCSI client, and used for the services within client. There will be two different VG layer in one disk, one VG within another.

If your LVM subsystem scans for VGs within the first layer LVs, newly discovered second Layer VGs and LVs within it will be mapped to the Target server. Since LV's are mapped to the target server (by devicemapper), lio_target modules will fail to load them as backstores.

```
[root@target ~]# pvs
  PV                 VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/mapper/mpatha STORAGE_POOL lvm2 a--  12.00t 2.50t
[root@target ~]# lvs
  LV     VG               Attr   LSize
  DISK_1 STORAGE_POOL -wi-ao---- 5.00t
  DISK_2 STORAGE_POOL -wi-ao---- 1.00t
  DISK_3 STORAGE_POOL -wi-ao---- 2.50t
  DISK_4 STORAGE_POOL -wi-ao---- 1.00t
[root@target ~]#
```

LVM searches for VGs and LVs during booting OS. That is why you didn't realized the issue in first place.

You should set a LVM filter to scan for new VGs within disks. See lvm.conf manual for global_filter. Using this configuration, you will be able to discard second layer VGs. Below is a sample for above storage architecture, only to scan VGs within PVs, and discard rest of all block devices.

```
[root@target ~]# diff /etc/lvm/lvm.conf{,.orginal}
152d151
<       global_filter = [ "a|/dev/mapper/mpath.|", "r|.*/|" ]
[root@target ~]#
```

You can simply use a script for running "vgchange -an 2nd_layer_VG" after bootup and restore LIO-target configuration. However i suggest using LVM's "global_filter" feature.

Note: Before CentOS 7/Red Hat 7, there was no problem on initilizing the second layer LVs, targetd were still able to load them as LUNs. However, new linux-iscsi(LIO) failt in that situation. I didn't reaserch the issue further.

Regards...

Comment: I just wished you had answered this question a bit earlier, this seems like exactly what my situation was, an iSCISI initiator used the storage blocks to create another VG, since this did not happen on production environment after spending some days on this issue i decided to give up and remove the second layer VGs/LVs and restore targetcli configuration, i will simulate the issue and try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running target.service at boot in order to restore the LIO configuration, and also ensure that iscsid.service is running to export your LIO devices and that tgtd is not running since it will conflict with the other LIO daemons.

Should look something like this,

```
root@centos7host# systemctl | grep "target.service\|iscsi"
iscsi-shutdown.service                                                                                               
loaded active exited    Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown
iscsi.service                                                                                                        
loaded active exited    Login and scanning of iSCSI devices
iscsid.service                                                                                                       
loaded active running   Open-iSCSI
iscsiuio.service                                                                                                     
loaded active running   iSCSI UserSpace I/O driver
target.service                                                                                                       
loaded active exited    Restore LIO kernel target configuration
iscsid.socket                                                                                                        
loaded active running   Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket
iscsiuio.socket                                                                                                      
loaded active running   Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket
```

You'll also want to cleanup whatever you did before this because it'll get confusing.  You've likely got volumes that were created outside of LIO so when you go to manage them with targetcli later you'll have some things that are not properly exported and it'll become confusing.

If it's possible I'd recommend wiping the system and making a clean start if you have this option.  Getting the iscsi subsystem setup correctly from the start is pretty important since it's dangerous to work with after it's running since you've got a lot of potentially destructive actions you can make to your users data.

Answer (score 0):

OK i can resolve my problem in RHEL8

i found error in target service that targetcli:loadconfig unable run because all time restart os will use disk before targetcli

i must enter command : `vgchange -an "Volumegroupname"` for refresh the disk

and enter : `targetcli`

and command : `restore`

for load config in targetcli

so i add this in `/etc/systemd/system/target.service`:

```
ExecStart=vgchange -an "ISCSIVolumeGroup1 ISCSIVolumeGroup2 ISCSIVolumeGroup3"

ExecStart=/usr/bin/targetctl restore

ExecStop=/usr/bin/targetctl clear
```

after i do : `cp /lib/systemd/system/target.service /etc/systemd/system/target.service`

1 more important you should disable autosave in targetcli with : `set global auto_save_on_exit=false`

it will don't save incorrect config but you must manual saveconfig all time that you new config in targetcli

hope this can help someone for same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try:

Edit /etc/lvm/lvm.conf

Add this:

```
filter = [ "r|/dev/sdb|", "r|/dev/sdc|", "a/.*/" ]
```

then execute in terminal：

```
update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
```

And reboot

Have a good luck!